# Why am I getting a PDO Exception error when I try to run Drupal Console inside the root directory?

Tags: 8

I've installed Drupal [Console](https://www.drupal.org/project/console) and can confirm it is in the proper directory, etc.

I run the command "Drupal" from my home directory and I see a Drupal Console help list of commands, but when I run it inside my site root directory, I get a PDO Exception error. I can't figure this one out. Should I move Drupal Console into my Drupal site directory? Thanks for the help. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update below in your `php.ini`. You need to define php for correct location for `.sock` file.

```
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

**OR**

If you will not getting result then try to replace below in your `settings.php` file.

**Replace** `'host' => 'localhost'`,

**With** `'host' => '127.0.0.1'`,

Comment: I actually was able to eventually figure this out. But you're correct, this is exactly what it was. I had to replace 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1'. Thanks a lot for your time and help though.